# Performing migration programmatically in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Given I have a path to Doctrine migration classes. How could I perform the migration programmatically in Doctrine 2?

I assume there should be a clean way to perform the migration over the API as it could have be done with earlier versions of Doctrine as described here:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/migrations.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work with Doctrine in Symfony framework and found this question looking for ways to run the migrations from outside of the command, keep in mind you can access the already-configured DependencyFactory through autowiring. To do that, expose the service using an alias:

```
services:
    Doctrine\Migrations\DependencyFactory:
        alias: 'doctrine.migrations.dependency_factory'
```

and autowire as usual:

```
public function someControllerAction(DependencyFactory $df): Response {
```

Done.

In saying so, during normal operation, **chances are you should be connecting to the database with a restricted user with no management permissions**, following the least-privilege principle. If you do that, running the migrations from your app will fail. If you don't, consider doing it.

I found the above code to be useful to include the migration information in my health check endpoint response, not necessarily to run the migrations as such.

Answer (score 2):

As I don't see any answers, I'll try to provide my solution for performing migration programmatically (with code) in doctrine.

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\Configuration\Configuration;
use Doctrine\Migrations\Configuration\Connection\ExistingConnection;
use Doctrine\Migrations\Configuration\Migration\ExistingConfiguration;
use Doctrine\Migrations\DependencyFactory;
use Doctrine\Migrations\Metadata\Storage\TableMetadataStorageConfiguration;
use Doctrine\Migrations\MigratorConfiguration;
use Doctrine\Migrations\Provider\SchemaProvider;
use Doctrine\Migrations\Version\Direction;

// connection
$dbParams = [
    'dbname' => 'database-name',
    'user' => 'database-username',
    'password' => 'database-password',
    'host' => 'hostname',
    'port' => 'port',
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
];
try {
    $connection = DriverManager::getConnection($dbParams);
} catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Problem connecting to DB. '.$e->getMessage();
    die();
}

// configuration - Be careful what namespace you use
$configuration = new Configuration($connection);
$configuration->addMigrationsDirectory('MyAppNamespace\Migrations', __DIR__ . '/../migrations');
// we want the execution of the migration to make changes to the table doctrine_migration_versions - so the system is aware that executed the migration
$storageConfiguration = new TableMetadataStorageConfiguration();
$storageConfiguration->setTableName('doctrine_migration_versions');
$configuration->setMetadataStorageConfiguration($storageConfiguration);

$dependencyFactory = DependencyFactory::fromConnection(
    new ExistingConfiguration($configuration),
    new ExistingConnection($connection))
);
$planCalculator = $dependencyFactory->getMigrationPlanCalculator();

// which migration to execute / I assume latest /
$latestMigrationVersion = $dependencyFactory->getVersionAliasResolver()->resolveVersionAlias('latest');

// check if we have at least one migration version to execute
if(!$latestMigrationVersion->equals(new Version(0))){ 
    try {
        // so we will execute only latest ONE migration, if you need more, just find a way to list them in the first parameter of method getPlanForVersions()
        $planUp = $planCalculator->getPlanForVersions(
            [$latestMigrationVersion],
            Direction::UP
        );
        $dependencyFactory->getMetadataStorage()->ensureInitialized();

        // do the migration
        $dependencyFactory->getMigrator()->migrate($planUp, (new MigratorConfiguration())->setAllOrNothing(false));
    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo 'There were problems during db-migration.'."\n".$e->getMessage()."\n\n";
    }
}
```

Hope it helps another developer to quick start his prototype.
I tried to be detailed about the code, so people do not waste time into figuring out every single dependency.

Answer (score -3):

Asuming you are using Symfony's [DoctrineMigrationsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html)

To migrate to the latest available version use:`doctrine:migrations:migrate` command.

[Here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#usage) are more available commands.

Comment: Thanks @laurynas. I know you can run it from the command line, but I was looking for a programmatic way to do that.

Comment: @TomasLiubinas maybe this is what you are looking for. [How to Call a Command from a Controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html)

Just change the command and parameters from the given example.